# the paragraph seems it's not a part of the parent

Tags: css

I am a junior in css
I have a footer and 2 paragraph in it
but when I Give border to the footer

```css
footer {
 border: 2px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <footer>
      <p>
        واخر دعوانا ان الحمد لله رب العالمين
        <a href=""> اللهم احسن خاتمتنا </a>
      </p>

      <p>اللهم انى اسألك حسن الخاتمة</p>
    </footer>
```

only the first paragraph is bordered
the second paragraph  not bordered as like it's not a part of the footer

[image]

Comment: Your border is around the footer, not the paragraphs. You also set a height on the footer so the second paragraph can't fit within it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've given the `<footer>` an explicit height of `50px`, but the text within it exceeds that height.  So you're seeing it overflow from the container.

You can remove the `height`:

```css
footer {
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p>
    واخر دعوانا ان الحمد لله رب العالمين
    <a href=""> اللهم احسن خاتمتنا </a>
  </p>
  <p>اللهم انى اسألك حسن الخاتمة</p>
</footer>
```

Or, I suppose depending on what you *want* to do, other options include handling the overflow differently.  For example, if for some reason it *must* be `50px` in height and you want the user to scroll to see the rest of the content:

```css
footer {
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p>
    واخر دعوانا ان الحمد لله رب العالمين
    <a href=""> اللهم احسن خاتمتنا </a>
  </p>
  <p>اللهم انى اسألك حسن الخاتمة</p>
</footer>
```

Other options include modifying the `<p>` styles *within* the `<footer>` to reduce the whitespace so that it fits within the intended height, etc.  How you want to style it is up to you, but the original problem was simply that the *contents* didn't fit the *container*.

Comment: woow it's a simple and I am glade ... Thank you Brother i will mark it after 7 minute :)

Comment: @AhmedSaif: I wouldn't take it personally.  I get down-voted all the time too.  People have a variety of reasons.  Some may think the question was too simple and should have been solved easily, some may think not enough detail was included regarding why it was problematic in the first place, and so on.  As long as you were able to solve the problem, that's really all that matters.